# How to check if a value has changed and update that value in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom rake task (Mechanize) that fetches order information (every hour) like order id, customer name and order status from a certain website and saves it to the database.

Here's the code:

```
desc "Login to exampleShop, fetch all the order information, save it to the database"
task :task_1 => :environment do
    require 'mechanize'

    puts "BEGIN - Task 1 - Checking exampleShop for new orders"

    a = Mechanize.new

    a.get('http://exampleshop.nl/admin/') do |page|

        # Select the login form
        login_form = page.forms.first

        # Insert the username and password
        login_form.username = 'username'
        login_form.password = 'password'

        # Submit the login information
        dashboard_page = a.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

        # Check if the login was successfull
        puts check_1 = dashboard_page.title == 'Dashboard' ?  "CHECK 1 DASHBOARD SUCCESS" : "CHECK 1 DASHBOARD FAIL"

        # Visit the orders index page to scrape some standard information
        orders_page = a.click(dashboard_page.link_with(:text => /Bestellingen/))

        # pp orders_page # => http://pastebin.com/L3zASer6

        # Check if the visit is successful
        puts check_2 = orders_page.title == 'Bestellingen' ?  "CHECK 2 ORDERS SUCCESS" : "CHECK 2 ORDERS FAIL"

        # Search for all #singleOrder table row's and put them in variable all_single_orders
        all_single_orders = orders_page.search("#singleOrder") 

        # Print information to the console
        puts "START fetching and saving information"

        # Scrape the needed information (the actual save to database is omitted)
        all_single_orders.each do |order|
            # Set links for each order
            order_link = order.at_css("a")['href']  #Assuming first link in row

            order_id = order.search("#orderId").text                    
            order_status = order.search("#orderStatus").text        
            order_revenue = order.search("#orderAmount").text       

            # Visit a single order page to fetch more detailed information
            single_order_page = orders_page.link_with(:href => order_link).click

            first_name = single_order_page.search(".firstName").text
            last_name = single_order_page.search(".lastName").text
            city = single_order_page.search(".city").text
            postal_code = single_order_page.search(".postalCode").text
            address = single_order_page.search(".address").text
            email = single_order_page.search(".email").text
            order_quantity = single_order_page.search(".orderQuantity").text

            single_order = Order.create(    order_id: order_id, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, city: city,
                                                        email: email, postal_code: postal_code, address: address, order_quantity: order_quantity,
                                                        order_revenue: order_revenue, order_status: order_status)


        end

        # Print information to the console
        puts "DONE fetching and saving information"
    end

    puts "END - Task 1 - Checking exampleShop for new orders"
end
```

I don't want the database to get cluttered and have a uniqueness validator set. This is the current `Order` model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :order_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

Here's a scenario sketch:

```
# Point in time 1
order_status = "Order received"

# Point in time 2
order_status = "Order shipped"
```

When at point in time 1, the rake task will fetch all the relevant order information, the `order_status` will be "Order received".

When at point 2, the rake task starts fetching the order information again. But this time I want it to check if the `order_status` has changed, if so it has to update the order without adding a new order to the database.

What is the best way to get this done? I'm using Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0.0.

#### UPDATE

The question is about the second part. I want the code to check if the order_status has changed, if so it has to update the relevant order with the new order_status value.

#### UPDATE 2

I've added the following to my custom rake task

```
single_order = Order.find_or_create_by(order_id: order_id, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, city: city,
                                            email: email, postal_code: postal_code, address: address, order_quantity: order_quantity,
                                            order_revenue: order_revenue, order_status: order_status)

unless single_order.valid?
    single_order.order_status = order_status
    puts single_order.save!
end
```

This gives me the following output:

```
BEGIN - Task 1 - Checking exampleShop for new orders
CHECK 1 DASHBOARD SUCCESS
CHECK 2 ORDERS SUCCESS
START fetching and saving information
rake aborted!
Validation failed: Order has already been taken
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
/Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/fstool/lib/tasks/task_1.rake:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `block in each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `upto'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/fstool/lib/tasks/task_1.rake:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize.rb:434:in `get'
/Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/fstool/lib/tasks/task_1.rake:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => task_1
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Just a quick style police check here. Why are you using instance variables like `@order_quantity` etc in a loop. That is not a good practice, you are breaking the visibility there.

Comment: Since I'm a beginner, good practice tips are always welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,

You can do

```
order = Order.new(order_params)
if order.valid? #no error on uniq
   order.save
end
```

I'm not so sure about the last part you mentioned.
but you can check if the order_status is changed by

```
@order.order_status_changed?
```

Here the documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

```
single_order = Order.create(order_id: order_id, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, city: city, email: email, postal_code: postal_code, address: address, order_quantity: order_quantity, order_revenue: order_revenue, order_status: order_status)

if single_order.valid?
  single_order.save
else
  order = Order.find(order_id)
  order.order_status = "SOMETHING"
  order.save!
end
```

Comment: yeah, and you could use `find_or_create_by`.

Comment: The question is mainly about the second part. I want the code to check if the order_status has changed, if so it has to update the relevant order with the new order_status value.

Comment: @Nich, the `validates :order_id, uniqueness: true` prevents a duplicate order from getting saved to the database. What's the benefit of using your suggested code in `task_1.rake`?

Comment: I think when you do save and it hits the same record in rake task, it will throw you error and break the loop(your rake task). You need to check whether is valid then save it. @narzero so are you checking specific order whether the order_Status is changed? If so, you can use my suggestion, else I'm not sure what you can do..

Comment: if you use `find_or_create_by` with the unique `order_id` you won't have that problem dude!

Comment: @phoet what about the second part ( I want the code to check if the order_status has changed, if so it has to update the relevant order with the new order_status value.)?

Comment: @phoet with `validates :order_id, uniqueness: true` set, it won't update the `order_id` because it already finds an order with the same `order_id` in the database and stops. I also tried with `find_or_create_by`, still the same.

Comment: why would it stop because of the order_id? there is nothing duplicated in the database, you just update the record that already exists.

Comment: then you should do @order.valid? ,if valid? return false, that mean it already find the same order_id and you just update the record instead? @narzero

Comment: @Nich take a look at Update 2. I get a `Validation failed: Order has already been taken` error.

Comment: @narzero check my update? whether it help u ? some basic idea